Implementing Load Balancing for Multiple Validator Nodes on AWS: Seeking Suggestions
I've set up two instances on AWS, each running a validator node for a blockchain project. Here’s a quick breakdown of my configuration:

First Server: Runs a validator node and a reverse proxy. It's also configured to handle --rpc-max-connections 2500. I am using this server to fetch data from polkadot.js.
Second Server: Runs another validator node using a key obtained from the first node.

My first server works well until it reaches the limit of 2500 connections, after which it cannot serve any more requests. This has led me to consider implementing load balancing to manage connections more effectively.
I suspect that traditional load-balancing methods might not be suitable for this setup. I am looking for advice or suggestions on how to implement a robust load-balancing solution that can handle these specific needs. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Normally load balancing would be done by services like nginx/haproxy (locally) or cloudflare (external). If you are using polkadot.js I suppose you have some kind of ssl enabled proxying already (nginx?) so you could also extend that for load balancing?
Your setup is not totally clear to me, you are using "a key obtained from the first node"? Maybe for clearer answers it would be good to define your setup better if above solutions are not what you are searching.
